# Parse JSON array and object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google analytics API to get a JSON message from the server. The message I receive is this one :

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:landingPagePath"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:pageviews",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:sessions",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/-chandigarh/axis-bank-sarsini-branch_chandigarh_chg_850458.html"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/267249-1.compliance-alex.xyz"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "29",
                  "10"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/267249-1.compliance-don.xyz"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "27",
                  "9"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/267249-1.compliance-fred.xyz"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "20",
                  "7"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/abohar/axis-bank-the-fazilka-central-cooperative-bank-ltd-branch_abohar_frp_135.html"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/about-us/career.htm"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "8",
                  "5"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/about-us/company-profile.htm"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "34",
                  "14"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/about-us/infrastructure.htm"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "3",
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/adilabad/gk-hospital-multispeciality-care_adilabad_adi_399806.html"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "2",
                  "1"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "/ahmedabad/akhani-jagdish-kumar_ahmedabad_ahd_1124498.html"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "7",
                  "3"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "3420452",
              "1333496"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 347614,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "0",
              "1"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "56660",
              "49274"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "isDataGolden": true
      },
      "nextPageToken": "1000"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse it and saved data in variable. How will I parse it. I tried many options but didn't get any data from JSON. Result is showing like **undefined**. I want to fetch the array data of **dimensions** and **values** like:

```
var a = "/-chandigarh/axis-bank-sarsini-branch_chandigarh_chg_850458.html";

var b = 1;

var c = 1;
```

Comment: have you tried [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse json?

Comment: "I tried many options" — where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Yes @KevinKloet I already tried this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Can someone explain the upvote here?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your JSON input is stored in the `json` variable, you could just do:

```js
var json = '{"reports":[{"columnHeader":{"dimensions":["ga:landingPagePath"],"metricHeader":{"metricHeaderEntries":[{"name":"ga:pageviews","type":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:sessions","type":"INTEGER"}]}},"data":{"rows":[{"dimensions":["/-chandigarh/axis-bank-sarsini-branch_chandigarh_chg_850458.html"],"metrics":[{"values":["1","1"]}]},{"dimensions":["/267249-1.compliance-alex.xyz"],"metrics":[{"values":["29","10"]}]},{"dimensions":["/267249-1.compliance-don.xyz"],"metrics":[{"values":["27","9"]}]},{"dimensions":["/267249-1.compliance-fred.xyz"],"metrics":[{"values":["20","7"]}]},{"dimensions":["/abohar/axis-bank-the-fazilka-central-cooperative-bank-ltd-branch_abohar_frp_135.html"],"metrics":[{"values":["1","1"]}]},{"dimensions":["/about-us/career.htm"],"metrics":[{"values":["8","5"]}]},{"dimensions":["/about-us/company-profile.htm"],"metrics":[{"values":["34","14"]}]},{"dimensions":["/about-us/infrastructure.htm"],"metrics":[{"values":["3","1"]}]},{"dimensions":["/adilabad/gk-hospital-multispeciality-care_adilabad_adi_399806.html"],"metrics":[{"values":["2","1"]}]},{"dimensions":["/ahmedabad/akhani-jagdish-kumar_ahmedabad_ahd_1124498.html"],"metrics":[{"values":["7","3"]}]}],"totals":[{"values":["3420452","1333496"]}],"rowCount":347614,"minimums":[{"values":["0","1"]}],"maximums":[{"values":["56660","49274"]}],"isDataGolden":true},"nextPageToken":"1000"}]}'

// Parse the JSON into the data variable
var data = JSON.parse(json);

data.reports.forEach(report => {
  report.data.rows.forEach(row => {
    // row.dimensions will contain your 'dimensions' array
    console.log(row.dimensions);
    
    row.metrics.forEach(metric => {
      // metric.values will contain your 'values' array
      console.log(metric.values);
    });
  });
});
```

You will just have to store these properties into your own variables.

Comment: @ArunaRajput: by _exact solution_, do you mean store the properties in variables?

Comment: Then don't hesitate to share with us how you solved your problem, @ArunaRajput

Answer (score -2):

Use json.parse

```js
    var json = '{"param1":1,"param2":2}',
        obj = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(obj.param1);
```

Most browsers e.g. Google support JSON.parse, moreover for those which don't support you can use json2 -> https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: this is not helpful for me. I'm not getting data from this syntax. thanks